# extracting all expansions from python's glob

Tags: python, glob

Python's glob module allows to specify wildcards to list files, and it's very practical getting *the files*.

But how can I get/reconstruct the values that were matched by the wildcards?

For example, say that I have these 8 files: `fa1 fa2 fa3 fb1 fb3 fc1 fc2 fc3` (note: `fb2` is missing).

I can do

```
import glob
glob.glob('f[ab][12]') # ['fa2', 'fb1', 'fa1']
```

In this case, I have 2 wildcards: `[ab]` and `[12]`. Each of them matches the values `a`, `b` and `1` and `2`, but only 3 combinations of these values come out, because one file, `fb2` (a valid combination of wildcards`) does not exist.

***Question:*** how can I get the list of the *valid* matching values for each wildcard? More precisely: how do I get the list of tuples of (string) values that matched to actually existing files?

In my example, I would like to get the list of tuples: `[('a', '2'), ('b', '1'), ('a', '1')]`.

Note that:

1. I don't want to get full names, just the values matched by wildcards (in my example, the prefix `'f'` is not part of the wildcard, therefore I don't want to get it in the list of tuples);
2. This must work for all the supported wildcards, including * and ?.

The only solution I can come up with is to use regex, but this basically means to re-implement the whole glob mechanism to extract intermediate data.

## EDIT

Since I got a close proposal due to "too broad" question (???), I reformulate the question as: is it possible to get that result using glob/fnmatch modules and not using directly regex?

Comment: I'm curious as to why you need those tuples? Maybe there's a better way to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: I have to do a specific computation per every possible combination of matching values in each wildcard. I don't really need "tuples", but I have to enumerate any possible combination of values matched by the wildcards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That info isn't available via those modules. `glob` calls `fnmatch` to do the pattern matching and `fnmatch` does the pattern-matching work using a regex. See the [glob](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Lib/glob.py) and [fnmatch](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Lib/fnmatch.py) Python sources.

---

Here's some Python 2 demo code that uses a modified version of the `translate` function from `fnmatch`. From my brief tests it *seems* to work, but no guarantees are given. :) Note that this ignores the other actions performed by `fnmatch`, eg case-insensitive matching.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import re, fnmatch, glob

def pat_translate(pat):
    """Translate a shell PATTERN to a regular expression.

    There is no way to quote meta-characters.
    Hacked to add capture groups
    """
    i, n = 0, len(pat)
    res = ''
    while i < n:
        c = pat[i]
        i = i+1
        if c == '*':
            res = res + '(.*)'
        elif c == '?':
            res = res + '(.)'
        elif c == '[':
            j = i
            if j < n and pat[j] == '!':
                j = j+1
            if j < n and pat[j] == ']':
                j = j+1
            while j < n and pat[j] != ']':
                j = j+1
            if j >= n:
                res = res + '\\['
            else:
                stuff = pat[i:j].replace('\\','\\\\')
                i = j+1
                if stuff[0] == '!':
                    stuff = '^' + stuff[1:]
                elif stuff[0] == '^':
                    stuff = '\\' + stuff
                res = '%s([%s])' % (res, stuff)
        else:
            res = res + re.escape(c)
    return res + '\Z(?ms)'


def test(shell_pat):
    print 'Shell pattern %r' % shell_pat
    names = glob.glob(shell_pat)
    print 'Found', names
    regex = pat_translate(shell_pat)
    print 'Regex %r' % regex
    pat = re.compile(regex)
    groups = [pat.match(name).groups() for name in names]
    print 'name, groups'
    for name, row in zip(names, groups):
        print name, row
```

Comment: The "dirty work" is made by `translate`, which actually helps a lot by converting the wildcard to regex. One idea could be to artificially wrap wildcards by `(` and `)` to create groups, but it a bit tricky because `re.escape` is used.

Comment: I don't _think_ we need to worry about `re.escape` since it's only used to escape non-pattern stuff. I've hacked together a simple example. I'll add it to my answer shortly.

Comment: I was thinking about hacking `translate` in this way: adding special sequences around the wildcards (e.g. `my_file_*` would become `my_file_BEGSTAR*ENDSTAR`), having translate to make a regex out of it, then replace the sequences with `()` to build a group and recompile the regex `my_file_(.*)`. Yes: the sequences may clash with the string content, but it can be avoided. Yes: not really efficient or clean, but reuses old code.

Answer (score 1):

In your specific case, you might want to use `itertools.product`:

```
import itertools
import os


def get_wildcards(*specs):
    for wildcard in itertools.product(*specs):
        if os.path.exists('f{}{}'.format(*wildcard)):
            yield wildcard


for wildcard in get_wildcards('ab', '12'):
    print wildcard
```

Output:

```
('a', '1')
('a', '2')
('b', '1')
```

In this case, you are taking the "product" of *"ab"* and *"12"* and ends up with 4 tuples, the `os.path.exists` test elliminate those tuples which do not specify existing files.

## Update

The plan is to turn a file-system wildcard into a regular expression (you can avoid using regular expression, but it will be painful). Next, we will list all files in the current directory, match each one against the regular expression. If a match found, we will construct a tuple to yield that.

```
import re
import os


def regex_from_wildcard(wildcard):
    wildcard = wildcard.replace('.', r'\.')
    wildcard = wildcard.replace('[', '([').replace(']', '])')
    wildcard = wildcard.replace('?', r'(.)').replace('*', r'(.*)')
    wildcard = r'^{}$'.format(wildcard)
    wildcard = re.compile(wildcard)
    return wildcard


def generate_from_wildcards(wildcard):
    pattern = regex_from_wildcard(wildcard)
    for filename in os.listdir('.'):
        match_object = re.match(pattern, filename)
        if match_object:
            yield tuple(''.join(match_object.groups()))


# Test
for tup in generate_from_wildcards('f[bc]?'):
      print tup
```

A couple of notes:

- Since I am still unclear of what exactly what you want, the solution might be off in a few places
- If the wildcard contains non-wildcard characters such as `f`, a dot, then those are not included in the tuple.

Comment: What about the support for `?` and `*` wildcards?

Comment: Hai Vu: The pattern in the question is just an example, AkiRoss needs a more a general solution.

Comment: Please give examples of wildcards